# jquery deferred on geocode result

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, callback, deferred

So due to google maps geocoded being an async function, I have tried to use jquery deferred to pause a function until the results from a call to another function are ready.
What I am trying to do here is, get the city someone clicks on, then make another call to get the center of that city. So I need to pass back the results of that function to get the center of that city, and would like to push them to an array with information from the original function. I have never used deferred (only read about it for half a day!) so I am a little unsure as to how to do this.

The .when() does not seem to be delaying the function as I would expect, as the alert inside the .when seems to trigger before any alerts from the called function are returned.

Additionally, I cannot seem to get the results from the function to be passed back into the main function.

```
function getGroupLatLng(groupname){

var deferred = new $.Deferred();

     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': groupname}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

          alert(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
      } else {

      }
      deferred.resolve(results);

    });
    return deferred.promise();

}

function codeLatLng() {

  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function (results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        var city = extractLongFromAddress(results[0].address_components, "sublocality");

        var groups = [];

        if (city) {
            var townName=city;
            groups.push({name: townName,
                         type: "city"
            });
            alert("above");
            $.when(getGroupLatLng(townName)).then(function(results){ //I am trying to delay this function until the results form the getGroupLatLng(townName) are retrieved.
                        alert("inside");
                        groups.push({lat:results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                                     lng:results[0].geometry.location.lng()
                                             });
                            });
                            alert("below");
        }

        groups = JSON.stringify(groups);
        console.log(groups);

   });
}
```

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `getGroupLatLng()` should create a new `$.Deferred` and return the promise. Returning from inside the geocode callback won't do anything

Comment: @charliefl Thanks a bunch. Seems to work. I am still getting a typeError: 'undefined is not a function evaluating groups.push'. Any suggestions?